# My dog won't go on walks without my partner

Tags: dogs, training, anxiety

My dog will not go on walks without my partner. She will stop as we get down the street, put her tail between her legs, face back towards the house and will not move till we go back home. She has separation anxiety so I know this may be a factor.

Are there any suggestions on how I can fix this problem please?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] to see how this site works, it only takes a minute. We have a [very similar question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/29123/12501) that already has an answer. If it answers your question as well, we will mark yours as duplicate, which is not a negative thing. It's just meant to keep the site clean and help other people find the same information. If your question is different, please [edit] it to clarify the aspect that wasn't answered in the existing question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dog won't walk unless the whole house walks with him](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29123/dog-wont-walk-unless-the-whole-house-walks-with-him)